# How do I output data via `each` and sort it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite

I have a class `User`:

```
class user class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :username, :password
end
```

And also have three users in my database:

```
id username password
1    user5    pw5
2    user3    pw3
3    user2    pw2
```

My view looks like:

```
<% @users.each do |user| %>
  <%= User.username %>, <%= user.password %> <br />
<% end %>
```

The output data is sorted by the user's row id:

```
user5, pw5
user3, pw3
user2, pw2
```

How can I output it sorted by `username`?

```
user2, pw2
user3, pw3
user5, pw5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [sort](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Array.html#method-i-sort) to compare by `username`:

```
@users.sort { |x, y| x.username <=> y.username }.each do |user|
  # Your code
end
```

Also, assuming that you're using ActiveRecord to pull the records from the database, you can also use [order](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#ordering) to do your query which is going to be a better option as databases are meant to handle that sort of thing. :D

In your controller:

```
@users = User.order('username DESC')
```

Comment: Don't use `sort` for this, use `sort_by`. It will be faster over a large list. But it would be even faster to tell the DBM to return the records sorted in the correct order in the first place. That's what DBMs excel at.

Comment: @theTinMan do you have a ref for why sort_by is faster than sort?

Comment: Because I have run benchmarks. You can nose around StackOverflow and find them. Or search for information about Schwartzian Transform sorts. `sort` is faster for base objects and `sort_by` is faster whenever there is a computation or lookup performed to find the comparable value. That is why we have two different methods to sort lists.

Answer (score 1):

**ASC order**

```
<% @users.sort_by{|e| e[:username]}.each do |user| %>
  <%= user.username %>, <%= user.password %> <br />
<% end %>
```

**DESC order**

```
<% @users.sort_by{|e| e[:username]}.reverse.each do |user| %> <!-- or you can use @users.sort_by{|e| -e[:username]} -->
  <%= user.username %>, <%= user.password %> <br />
<% end %>
```

Comment: @Stefan : try `@users.sort_by{|e| e[:username]}.reverse` for desc order

Answer (score 0):

In controller I think your code is like

```
@users = User.all
```

You can change it into

```
@users = User.order(:username)
```

Now there is no need to change in views, it will be same

```
<% @users.each do |user| %>
<%= User.username %>, <%= user.password %> <br />
<% end %>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<% @users.sort{|u1,u2| u1.username <=> u2.username).each do |user| %>
<%= user.username %>, <%= user.password %> <br />
```

See the [`sort`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-sort) documentation.

Comment: `sort` is slower than `sort_by` for this.